# Testing characters of two Strings representing series of bits

Tags: java, string, methods

I am trying to compare two chains of bits and return either a V for TRUE and a F for False if either bit is "on", but it doesn't seem to work.

If I input 1000 and 0000, it produces `V F F F`, which is correct, but if I input 1000 and 0001, it returns `V V V V` and I can't seem to figure out why.

Where an I going wrong?

```
    public static String ou (String s1, String s2) {    
        String chaineOU = "";
        char verifS1 = 0;
        char verifS2 = 0;           

        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
            verifS1 = s1.charAt(i);
            for (int n = 0; n < s2.length(); n++){
                verifS2 = s2.charAt(n);
            }

            if (verifS1 == '1' || verifS2 == '1'){
                chaineOU = chaineOU + 'V';
            } else {
                chaineOU = chaineOU + 'F';

            }
            return chaineOU; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you looping in order to get `verifS2`? You're currently *only* using the last character in `s2`...

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop makes no sense. It causes you to only check the last character of s2 against all the characters of s1.

In addition, your return statement seems to be in the wrong place. It should be after the loop.

Just get rid of the inner loop and move the return statement :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
        verifS1 = s1.charAt(i);
        verifS2 = s2.charAt(i);

        if (verifS1 == '1' || verifS2 == '1'){
            chaineOU = chaineOU + 'V';
        }else{
            chaineOu = chaineOU + 'F';
        }
    }
    return chaineOU;
```

This code assumes that `s1` and `s2` have the same length. If they may have different lengths, you should decide what the output should be in this case, and change the code to reflect that.

Comment: What should I write so it checks all characters 1 by 1 instead of only using the last one? For exemple I want the first character to compare to the 1st one, 2nd to 2nd etc..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to perform an "OR" of the "bits" (reading the code, and considering "chaineOU" means "OR chain" in French), in which case you need to compare the *same* bits, so you want one loop instead two.

You also have the problem of returning from *within* the loop.

Try this:

```
public static String ou (String s1, String s2){

    String chaineOU = "";
    char verifS1 = 0;
    char verifS2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
        verifS1 = s1.charAt(i);
        verifS2 = s2.charAt(i);

        if (verifS1 == '1' || verifS2 == '1'){
            chaineOU = chaineOU + 'V';
        }else{
            chaineOU = chaineOU + 'F';
        }
    }
    return chaineOU; 
}
```

Your test case that worked was an unfortunate coincidence.

---

As an aside, this code could be rewritten more succinctly as:

```
public static String ou (String s1, String s2){
    String chaineOU = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
        chaineOU += s1.charAt(i) + s2.charAt(i) > 96 ? 'V' : 'F`;
    return chaineOU; 
}
```

See [live demo](http://rextester.com/SJVUP11164)

This simplification results from the following observations:

- a reference to the character is not required; it needs only to be compared, so delete the `char` variables
- a character is added to the result with an if-else that can more elegantly be expressed using a ternary
- `char` is a *numeric* type, that can be arithmetically *added*, and the character `'0'` is decimal `48`, so `'0' + '0'` is `96`. Logically, if either character is `'1'`, the sum of the characters will exceed `96`, leading to the more concise test for either character being `'1'`

Comment: Not sure where `n` came from, but I believe that you meant `i`.

Comment: thank you! Tried to fix that problem for hours and you just fixed it in 30seconds!